# android - Setting ScrollView height dynamically

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a layout wich is nested like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scrollAplicacoes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/titulo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:fontFamily="Arial"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="-5dp"
                android:text="@string/titulo_aplicacao"
                android:textColor="#3c3c3c"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnAplicacaoUm"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:onClick="selectAplicacao"
                android:src="@drawable/aplicacoes_item1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnAplicacaoDois"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:onClick="selectAplicacao"
                android:src="@drawable/aplicacoes_item2" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnAplicacaoTres"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:onClick="selectAplicacao"
                android:src="@drawable/aplicacoes_item3" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/menuFixo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/faixa_below" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/belowHome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/descBtnHome"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/below_home_sel" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/belowCalculadora"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="abreCalculadora"
            android:contentDescription="@string/descBtnCalculadora"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/below_calc" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/belowProdutos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/descFaixaProdutos"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/below_produtos" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that the LinearLayout outside the ScrollView, at the end is fixed on the bottom, and the scroll is placed behind it. So i need the Scroll to be the screen height minus this fixed LinerLayout height minus a little margin.

I tried this:

```
(...)
int scrollFInalHeight = scrollHeight - fixedMenuHeight - 10;

ViewGroup.LayoutParams param = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(scrollStartWidth, scrollFInalHeight);
scroll.setLayoutParams(param);
```

But the app crashes when I start this activity.
This java code is within the **public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)** method.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to put

```
android:layout_above="@+id/menuFixo"
```

in your ScrollView?

Comment: Indeed it makes sense, but it returns the error below, even though this is the correct ID for the LinearLayout below.

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/menuFixo').

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Add the + sign! It's happening because the compiler is reading the ids from the top. :)

Comment: Thanks! It's just fine now. But, ain't this + sign used to set the id, not select the id? It is one of those "i don't know why but works" stuff for me.

Comment: Kind of, you have to use the + when you are creating a new resource, and since the compiler reads the xml from the top you have to use the + sign where you refer to the resource for the first time. (it's confusing I know!). :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to set Height

```
scroll_view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

or

```
scroll_view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 350));
```

Answer (score 4):

@aNikeT's answer is correct, but it will be safer with

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = mDescriptionScrollView.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = scrollViewHeight;
```